# Link to CSS in Pug/Express is not working

Tags: css, express, pug

My paths are as such:

```
src
  index.ts
public
  css
    (css files)
views
  sections
    master.pug
```

In my index.ts I have this piece of code: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

So in my master.pug I wrote this, and thought it would work: `link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/style.css', type='text/css')`

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Something I'm overlooking? Any help would be great! I'll post my fix if I find one before something pops up here. :)

Comment: What is the full path of the css file on your server that you want to be served for that link tag?  And, what is the full path of `__dirname`?  We need to know these in order to suggest the proper solution.  For your current code to work, the style sheet needs to be in `__dirname + '/public/css/style.css'`.

Comment: Harshit Gupta provided a working solution. :) thanks for the effort though!

Comment: They made a lucky guess because there's not enough information in your question to know WHERE the `public` folder is.  Apparently it's located relative to the current working directory, NOT the module directory, but there's no way for us to know where it is.  So, the code in Harshit's answer makes your app dependent upon the current working directory when the app is started.

Comment: If you look in the `express.static()` [source code](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static/blob/master/index.js#L65), you will see that it takes whatever path you give it and calls `path.resolve(yourpath)` on it which resolves relative paths vs. the current working directory which is whatever the OS current working directory is when your app is started.  Usually, you don't want to depend upon that.  It would usually be better to specify a path relative to the module or project.  But, you haven't told us where it is relative to the module so we can't suggest what that code would be.

Comment: Oh! My bad y'all, my written indents didn't count, I'm new to SO. Fixed now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this, `app.use(express.static('public'));` Here public is folder name which contain all static files and your public folder should be on same hierarchy level.